# How to access rear and front speaker of Android phones?

Tags: android, speaker

I want to access rear and front speakers of android phones, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(!audioOption)
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
else
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire either a rear speaker or a front earpiece at time.

If no accessory connected;

Use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);` to use front speaker/earpiece. But this would play audio in earpiece not on speaker. To use rear speaker, use`audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`

If accessory connected;
 Use `audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);` to use front speaker/earpiece. But this would play audio in earpiece not on speaker. To use rear speaker, use`audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);` & `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`

Note: Make sure `audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(boolean on)` and `audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(boolean on)` set to **false**.